# How to specify multiple One-To-One relations in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I have two models:

```
Deal
 - id
 - seller
 - buyer
 - price
 - date

Person
 - id
 - name
 - balance
 - email
```

The `Deal` model fields `seller` and `buyer` contain `Person` model instances.

What is the correct way to specify this models in Laravel Eloquent?

---

I try to do it this way. Database schema:

```
deals
 - id: int, primary
 - seller_id: int
 - buyer_id: int
 - price: decimal(10, 2)
 - date: datetime

people
 - id: int, primary
 - name: string
 - balance: decima(10, 2)
 - email: string
```

Eloquent models definition:

```
class Deal extends Model
{
    public function seller()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Person::class, 'seller_id');
    }

    public function buyer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Person::class, 'buyer_id');
    }
}

class Person extends Model
{
    //
}
```

But when I try to create a new `Deal` instance:

```
$seller = new Person();
$seller->name = 'Anna';
$seller->balance = 100500;
$seller->email = 'anna@exampe.com';

$buyer = new Person();
$buyer->name = 'Bob';
$buyer->balance = 9000;
$buyer->email = 'bob@exampe.com';

$deal = new Deal();
$deal->seller = $seller;
$deal->buyer = $buyer;
$deal->price = 99.99;
$deal->date = new Carbon();

$deal->save();
```

I get an error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'buyer' in 'field list'...
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `$deal->seller`, it returns you an instance of `People` object as you have defined your relations in that way. But while saving, you can do that. Try this

```
$seller = new Person();
$seller->name = 'Anna';
$seller->balance = 100500;
$seller->email = 'anna@exampe.com';
$seller->save(); // important

$buyer = new Person();
$buyer->name = 'Bob';
$buyer->balance = 9000;
$buyer->email = 'bob@exampe.com';
$buyer->save(); // important

$deal = new Deal();
$deal->seller_id = $seller->id;
// or $deal->seller()->associate($seller);
$deal->buyer_id = $buyer->id;
// or $deal->buyer()->associate($buyer);
$deal->price = 99.99;
$deal->date = new Carbon();

$deal->save();
```

Comment: Thank you! The parent instance retrieving works this way `$seller = $deal->seller` so I expected associating to work the same way.

Answer (score 1):

For a [Belongs To Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships) you should use the `associate` method.

You'll also need to save the `Person` models first so that you will have a valid ID to relate in the database.

```
$seller = new Person();
$seller->name = 'Anna';
$seller->balance = 100500;
$seller->email = 'anna@exampe.com';
$seller->save();

$buyer = new Person();
$buyer->name = 'Bob';
$buyer->balance = 9000;
$buyer->email = 'bob@exampe.com';
$buyer->save();

$deal = new Deal();
$deal->seller()->associate($seller);
$deal->buyer()->associate($buyer);
$deal->price = 99.99;
$deal->date = new Carbon();

$deal->save();
```

Comment: Thank you! The parent instance retrieving works this way `$seller = $deal->seller` so I expected associating to work the same way.